# MapSceneConfig to modify the language does not seem to work on Android 13

Tags: here-api

Sorry, I recently found that on Android 13, using MapSceneConfig to modify the language does not seem to work, can you please confirm?
I really need your help, Thank you!
I'm using the lite version.
I tried to change it to zh_tw to show Taiwanese streets.

[image: layer image of a map]

```
MapSceneConfig mapSceneConfig = new MapSceneConfig();

mapSceneConfig.mainLanguageCode = LanguageCode.ZH_TW;
mapSceneConfig.fallbackLanguageCode = LanguageCode.ZH_TW;

mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapStyle.NORMAL_DAY, mapSceneConfig, new MapScene.LoadSceneCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadScene(@Nullable MapScene.ErrorCode errorCode) {
                if (errorCode == null) {
                    mapItemsExample = new MapItemsExample(MiniActivity.this, mapView);
                    mapObjectsExample = new MapObjectsExample(mapView);
                    mapOverlayExample = new MapOverlayExample(MiniActivity.this, mapView);
                    setTapGestureHandler(mapView);

                    if (location != null) {
                        moveCamera(new GeoCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                        Log.e("location", "moveCameraonResume");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadScene failed: " + errorCode.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

I found that it works normally on Android 11, but not on Android 13.

Comment: Do you experience the same issue when not using MapSceneConfig to change the map labels? Ie. when you try the HelloMap example from GitHub?

Also, it may be worth to try another mapSceneConfig.fallbackLanguageCode - and not the same one - does it happen also with, e.g. EN_US?

Comment: I solved this problem by using the explore version directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MapSceneConfig class was updated in the last release 4.13.5 and would probably resolve issues related to different Android versions.